# Querying referenced collections using Mongoose Populate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, populate

I'm having a tricky time with Mongoose Populate(). I am trying to load referenced documents from another collection using the user id.

I have a user collection that is stored like this.

```
{
id: "myuserid",     // alphanumeric string. 
username: "Me"
sessions: []        // note that this is deliberately empty. 
}
```

I have a gamesessions collection that stores game save states like this:

```
{
    id: "gamesaveidstring", // unique id
    userId: "myuserid",     // the user who saved this. ("Me")
    properties: {}          // bunch of stuff that tracks what you doing in the game.
}
```

I would like to return an object that looks like this:

```
 {
    id: "myuserid",
    username: "Me",
    sessions: [{
        id: "gamesaveidstring",
        properties: {}
    },{
        id: "gamesaveidstring",
        properties: {}
    }, ...] // etc.
}
```

I have looked at the Mongoose documentation, but I'm not finding a clean way (that works) to accomplish this. I can do this by nesting queries, but I find that messy.

Populate seems to allow you to query another collection as part of your existing query.

This is how I'm trying to accomplish the query. This **successfully** returns the user object, but it is lacking the populate() queried `sessions: []` array.

```
User.findOne({_id: id})
    .populate({
        path: "sessions",        // where I want the data to go on the object
        select: 'properties id', // grab these fields  
        match: {userId: id},     // with this userId, same one I grabbed the user with.
        model: "GameSession",    // in this collection
        options: {limit: 5}      // but not all of them kthx.  
    })
    .exec(function(err, document) {
        res.json(document);
});
```

I have a user model

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    _id: String, 
    username: String,
    sessions: { type: String, ref:'GameSession'} // never actually stores the ID of the gamesession. I don't want this data stored in the user document because it is saved often and many sessions are created.  
});
```

And a game session model

```
var GameSession = new Schema({
    _id: String,
    userId: String,
    projectId: String
});
```

To quote the docs (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)
*"There are no joins in MongoDB but sometimes we still want references to documents in other collections. This is where population comes in."*

Yes, exactly, I have a user id, and I want to grab all the stuff with that user id from another collection and bundle it up with my user in an array called sessions. That is all.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, just for fun, I put a the ID of one of the sessions in the sessions: [] property on the user, and voila, the session appears. 

So I know now that I am still able to read and interpret documents and implement code. 

It appears as though however, that I can't just "make up" a parameter on my response and populate it using populate. I have to query separately. I think.

Comment: Ok, final thoughts. 

If you have an array of references in a parameter in your document, Populate works wonders. 

If you DON'T then you have to use something like async to grab all the stuff you need separately. Async really cleans up the nested callbacks, so If you have data queries like this I recommend it. 

I tried creating a virtual on the model, with a Find call nested in it, but that didn't seem to work.